# How to push the project I clone from GitHub to my own empty repo?

Tags: git, github

I have some issue about using git and GitHub.

I clone the LLVM project from its GitHub, and make some change by myself. So I may do some commit on local.

Now I want to push this whole project to my own repo on GitHub including my own commit.

I search some tutorial about this, and I did do some command to it.

Here is my command, and there are some errors:

1. I create an empty repo on my own GitHub account, let's name `myrepo`

```
$ git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000 # because the size of LLVM project is to large.
$ git push --mirror https://github.com/MyAccount/myrepo.git
# Run some information that is not error message.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/MyAccount/myrepo.git'
```

How do I fix that?

I have tried `git remote add original https://github.com/MyAccount/myrepo.git` and it show up that there is existing remote (llvm-project) for sure.

Comment: set the upstream and remote of the the repo on your computer so that git knows where to upload your code

Comment: Are you using git over https or ssh? Please add the flag `-vvv` to your `git push` command and provide the output.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by myself. And yes, I need to change the remote like comment said.

Here is what I do:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/MyAccount/myrepo.git
git push
```

That is, I can push this to my own repo now.

Thanks!!